# Only one row of two-row header showing in word using StyleRef field

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

I've been tasked with putting together a conference booklet in word that has headers that match the titles of each paper. I've inserted the StyleRef field corresponding to the title in the header, but the header only shows one line of longer titles, cutting off the end. I've tried making the header larger, and that has no effect. Any suggestions?

[image: Longer title being cut off by header]

Comment: Increase the height of the header?

Comment: The space allocated to the header will automatically expand to fit the content.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a bug - Make sure you are using the latest update to Word

Which version of Word are you using?

A workaround that has worked for many is to place three spaces after the StyleRef field.

Here is [my writing on the StyleRef field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF).

*If your header is inside a fixed-size table, either take it out of the table or change the size of the cell.*

Although Microsoft is aware of the bug, they think it is fixed. If your are using the latest version of Word, and it is still happening, be sure to use their [Feedback mechanisms](https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11) to let them know that the problem continues.